# Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization incorrect implementation

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra

I'm in the process of building a free open source OpenGL3-based 3D game engine (it's not a school assignment, rather it's for personal skill development and to give something back to the open source community). I've reached the stage where I need to learn lots of related math, so I'm reading a great textbook called "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics, 3rd Edition".

I've hit a snag early on trying to do the book's exercises though, as my attempt at implementing the "Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization algorithm" in C++ is outputting a wrong answer. I'm no math expert (although I'm trying to get better), and I have very limited experience looking at a math algorithm and translating it into code (limited to some stuff I learned from Udacity.com). Anyway, it would really help if someone could look at my incorrect code and give me a hint or a solution.

Here it is:

```
/*
The Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization algorithm is as follows:

    Given a set of n linearly independent vectors Beta = {e_1, e_2, ..., e_n},
    the algorithm produces a set Beta' = {e_1', e_2', ..., e_n'} such that
    dot(e_i', e_j') = 0 whenever i != j.

    A. Set e_1' = e_1
    B. Begin with the index i = 2 and k = 1
    C. Subtract the projection of e, onto the vectors e_1', e_2', ..., e_(i-1)'
       from e_i, and store the result in e_i', That is,

                             dot(e_i, e_k')
       e_i' = e_i - sum_over(-------------- e_k')
                                e_k'^2

    D. If i < n, increment i and loop back to step C.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

glm::vec3 sum_over_e(glm::vec3* e, glm::vec3* e_prime, int& i)
{
    int k = 0;
    glm::vec3 result;

    while (k < i-2)
    {
        glm::vec3 e_prime_k_squared(pow(e_prime[k].x, 2), pow(e_prime[k].y, 2), pow(e_prime[k].z, 2));
        result += (glm::dot(e[i], e_prime[k]) / e_prime_k_squared) * e_prime[k];
        k++;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 2;  // number of vectors we're working with
    glm::vec3 e[] = {
        glm::vec3(sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, 0),
        glm::vec3(-1, 1, -1),
        glm::vec3(0, -2, -2)
    };

    glm::vec3 e_prime[n];
    e_prime[0] = e[0];  // step A

    int i = 0;  // step B

    do  // step C
    {
        e_prime[i] = e[i] - sum_over_e(e, e_prime, i);

        i++;    // step D
    } while (i-1 < n);

    for (int loop_count = 0; loop_count <= n; loop_count++)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector e_prime_" << loop_count+1 << ": < " 
                  << e_prime[loop_count].x << ", " 
                  << e_prime[loop_count].y << ", " 
                  << e_prime[loop_count].z << " >" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs:

```
Vector e_prime_1: < 0.707107, 0.707107, 0 >
Vector e_prime_2: < -1, 1, -1 >
Vector e_prime_3: < 0, -2, -2 >
```

but the correct answer is supposed to be:

```
Vector e_prime_1: < 0.707107, 0.707107, 0 >
Vector e_prime_2: < -1, 1, -1 >
Vector e_prime_3: < 1, -1, -2 >
```

**Edit:** Here's the code that produces the correct answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

glm::vec3 sum_over_e(glm::vec3* e, glm::vec3* e_prime, int& i)
{
    int k = 0;
    glm::vec3 result;

    while (k < i-1)
    {
        float e_prime_k_squared = glm::dot(e_prime[k], e_prime[k]);
        result += ((glm::dot(e[i], e_prime[k]) / e_prime_k_squared) * e_prime[k]);
        k++;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 3;  // number of vectors we're working with
    glm::vec3 e[] = {
        glm::vec3(sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, 0),
        glm::vec3(-1, 1, -1),
        glm::vec3(0, -2, -2)
    };

    glm::vec3 e_prime[n];
    e_prime[0] = e[0];  // step A

    int i = 0;  // step B

    do  // step C
    {
        e_prime[i] = e[i] - sum_over_e(e, e_prime, i);

        i++;    // step D
    } while (i < n);

    for (int loop_count = 0; loop_count < n; loop_count++)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector e_prime_" << loop_count+1 << ": < " 
                  << e_prime[loop_count].x << ", " 
                  << e_prime[loop_count].y << ", " 
                  << e_prime[loop_count].z << " >" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at the modifiied gram schmidt process, which is described [here]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process, for example. Although the two methods are equivalent algebraically the modified method behaves far better with rounding errors and will give results that are more nearly orthogonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably in the way you define `e_k'^2`. As far as vector math goes, the square of a vector is usually taken to be the square of its norm. Therefore,

```
double e_prime_k_squared = glm::dot(e_prime_k, e_prime_k);
```

Moreover, dividing by a vector is undefined (I wonder why GLM allows it?), so if `e_k'^2` is a vector, the whole thing is undefined.

Comment: I changed the line in question as suggested (float e_prime_k_squared = glm::dot(e_prime[k], e_prime[k]);), and I get the exact same output as before...

Comment: There was an off-by-one error where I had written: while (k < i-2). It gives the right answer after changing it to: while (k < i-1), and changing e_prime_k_squared as you suggested. Thanks a lot for telling me it should be a scalar instead of a vector. I don't know why GLM lets me divide by a vector...